# RegExReplace - A few examples to get me started, please

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use RegExReplace to pre-process some text before it gets parsed for use in an Access database.  Currently I have been defining a growing number of string patterns into a table, then use the stock Replace() function in VBA using that table.  Works OK, but misses the mark in a few areas; I am pretty sure regular expressions will be a better long-term solution for me, but I am completely clueless how to construct them.

I'd like to see if the smart folks here can give me a leg up on the task using a few actual examples from my data, by illustrating the regex strings that will produce the desired result:

```
1.  6 IN                6IN
2.  12.3 IN X 2 YD      12.3IN_X_2YD
3.  6IN X 4IN           6IN_X_4IN
4.  8X120MM             8_X_120MM
5.  1 1/2"              1.5IN
6.  CAT, DOG            CAT DOG
7.  CAT,DOG             CAT DOG
8.  CAT ,DOG            CAT DOG
9.  CAT , DOG           CAT DOG
```

My patterns fail in ways like:   CATHETER INFUSION => CATHETERINFUSION

I will be using a multi-pass approach vs attempting to come-up with some terribly complex expressions.

Can anyone offer some initial guidance to any of these samples.  I'm confident I will be able to leverage these samples to extend as needed.

[Edit:] I did just find a few helpful examples:

```
 NewStr := RegExReplace("abc123123", "123$", "xyz")  ; Returns "abc123xyz" because the $ allows a match only at the end.
 NewStr := RegExReplace("abc123", "i)^ABC")  ; Returns "123" because a match was achieved via the case-insensitive option.
 NewStr := RegExReplace("abcXYZ123", "abc(.*)123", "aaa$1zzz")  ; Returns "aaaXYZzzz" by means of the $1 backreference.
 NewStr := RegExReplace("abc123abc456", "abc\d+", "", ReplacementCount)  ; Returns "" and stores 2 in ReplacementCount.
```

[Edit 2]:  Making good progress!

```
 strText = "BANDAGE, ADHESIVE,      2 FT    X 3.5 IN X 0.25MM, LATEX-FREE"

 strResult = RegExReplace(strText, "(,|\s+)", " ", True)                       
 strResult = RegExReplace(strResult, "\s+(IN|FT|YD)\s+", "$1 ", True) 
 strResult = RegExReplace(strResult, "\s+X\s+", "_X_", True)
```

Produces:

```
 BANDAGE ADHESIVE 2FT_X_3.5IN_X_0.25MM LATEX-FREE
```

Comment: Multi-pass is the only way to keep your sanity here. Don't attempt to do this in single pass.

Comment: What does this have to do with regex?

Comment: Unihedron, Excuse my syntax error.  It seemed logical to connect "RegexReplace" with "Regex" as the constructed string to find patterns to replace text are very similar to regex.  Any other pointers to offer?

Answer (score 0):

Some regexps that might be useful:

```
/\s+IN/IN/
/\s+X\s+/_X_/
/(?:\d)X(?:\d)/_X_/
```

Comment: `s/\s+X\s+/_X_/` doesn't work for `4.  8X120MM             8_X_120MM`, and `s/(?\d)X(?\d)/_X_/` is just... pattern syntax error

Comment: Unihedron, I realize no single pattern will solve my needs.  A multipass approach, in a defined sequence is needed.  While the example offered by Terje is not general purpose, it does begin to shine light on my request.